# How do you force GitHub pages to update?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm trying to make changes to the site I have deployed on GitHub Pages, but no matter how many times I deploy it WON'T update the "gh-pages" repo I need it to.

I've updated the code, then deployed about 3 times now and it says "Published":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGctZ.png

I've given it half hour now to update:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/14lBj.png

but it STILL hasn't applied the changes and is still using the last deployed version:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/caIs0.png

---

I've tried clearing cache, I've tried changing random files just to have more changes to deploy and see if it updates, nothing is working.

How do you update GitHub Pages after deploying? It's always been random if it would update or not for me. Sometimes I'll "run deploy" and it will update pages, and sometimes it won't. Right now it's not updating no matter how many times I try.

Do I have to "unpublish" then publish it again with the changes I made? How come it won't just update on a new deploy? Why is it stuck on the deploy I made 2 days ago?

EDIT:

And I have:

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

in the package-json, it's just always random when I actually run "deploy" though whether the "gh-pages" repo ACTUALLY gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

**1**-The solution was to edit the index.html file in the GitHub website. The website then updates on the web as expected.
Only changing one line into `index.html` made it "load" the "true" `index.html` and not all the previous commit.

**2**-If an empty `CNAME` file is located in the project then make sure the CNAME file contained a line with the domain you want to be built.

Comment: I'm deploying from the "gh-pages" repo though. There's no way to just force an update to the "gh-pages" branch? Githubs own instructions don't work.

Comment: i think you need to remove the remote and add it again in the folder in which your project is located, there might be possibilities that you add some other remote origin in the your project folder

Comment: i have updated the answer now you can try testing these updates! Hope it will work for you
and make sure you project contains atleast index.html file through which the Github pages starts the execution